# Remember scroll position only if it is the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am doing a quote website and i have about 300 quotes gruped on about 30 pages ( 10 quotes on  the page ).At every quote i have a like button so when i like a quote [THIS](http://code.hyperspatial.com/1337/remember-scroll-position/) javascript code remembers the scroll position. But the problem is that when i go to the next page this code remembers the scroll position but i want if the page is different from the previous one ( for example: if the user likes a quote on the page quotes.php?page=3 the javascript code remembers the scroll position of the website when the like button was pressed but if the user go to the bottom of the page and goes on another page by useing the navigation buttons scroll position remains the same like previous )the cookie that was created  to be deleted so the page scroll starts from 0 not from 200 for example.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7C2q.jpg) is an idea on how my website looks like on top at 0 scroll.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8unv.jpg) is an idea on how my website looks like on bottom at max scroll

Scroll position script is used in body

```
<body onunload="unloadP('UniquePageNameHereScroll')" onload="loadP('UniquePageNameHereScroll')">
```

Comment: can you explain the problem again, i dont think the question is in consistent English, i cant understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script defined the parameter "page name". Maybe you can try to assign different name per page.

```
<body onunload="unloadP('UniquePageNameHereScroll')" onload="loadP('UniquePageNameHereScroll')">
```

Eg.

```
<body onunload="unloadP('page1')" onload="loadP('page1')">
...
<body onunload="unloadP('page2')" onload="loadP('page2')">
```